# how to indicate multiple custom marker on map using fetch lat and long data from mysql db

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, latitude-longitude

i have try to fetch lat and long value from mysql db and pass those value on google map for show location marker on map

but currently i have fetch only last rows data so indicate marker only one place
how to display all location on map??

```
<?php
include "config.php";
$result="select * from ds_duty_history";
$a=mysqli_query($conn,$result);
// $count_row = mysqli_num_rows($a); 
while ($b = mysqli_fetch_array($a)) {
    $long_d=$b['lng'];
    $lat_d=$b['lat'];
    $result = array(array('latitude'=>$lat_d,'longitude'=>$long_d));
}
?>
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            // Set static latitude, longitude value
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat_d; ?>, <?php echo $long_d; ?>);
            // Set map options
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: latlng,
                panControl: true,
                zoomControl: true,
                scaleControl: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            // Create map object with options
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        <?php
            // uncomment the 2 lines below to get real data from the db
            // $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parkings");
            // while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            foreach($result as $row){ // <- remove this line
                echo "addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(".$row['latitude'].", ".$row['longitude']."), map);";}
        ?>
        }
        function addMarker(latLng, map) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                draggable: true, // enables drag & drop
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });

            return marker;
        }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div style="float:left; position:relative; width:550px; border:0px #000 solid;">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width:550px;height:400px;border:solid black 1px;"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

currently display only one marker i.e last fetch record lat and long assign on map
how to display all place on map using mysql lat,long value?

Comment: By "last rows" do you mean something like `ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 10`?

Comment: in table have latitude and longitude value and those are one or more record like different places and i have display location on map using those latitude and longitude value.....,using this code i have able to display only one place ...,so how to diplay all places on map??

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you have here is that you're not actually collecting different results in your `$result` variable but overwrite it with the most recent one. The also seems to be some abuse of the variable `$result` which might be contributing to your confusion. Let's say we declare a new `array` and call it `$rows`. Then we can collect *all* the rows with the following code (to substitute your first snippet):

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ds_duty_history";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rows = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $lon_d = $row['lng'];
    $lat_d = $row['lat'];
    // Use short-cut append syntax here so we add row and don't overwrite $rows
    $rows[] = ['latitude' => $lat_d, 'longitude' => $long_d];
}
?>
```

Now in your display code (the second snippet) you would be able to iterate over `$rows` pretty much like:

```
foreach ($rows as $row){ 
    // Do work with each $row here
}
```

---

Just as an aside, try to get used to using variable names that are as meaningful as possible and use new variables as much as you can. Trying to use short, generic variable names like `$a` will always lead to confusion since you won't know what it represents unless you find where you declared it every time. Trying to re-use a variable (like you did with `$result`) can make your life much more difficult since now even if you find an assignment to the variable, it is assigned many different times and (the way you used it) represents completely different types each time. Doing this one thing makes it just a little easier to get the hang of programming since at the very least you'll be able to read and make sense of your *own* intent when reading your *own* code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code for display multiple marker on map

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var LocationData = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
      function initialize()
      {
        var myOptions = {zoom:12,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROAD};
        var map =
        new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        for (var i in LocationData)
        {
          var p = LocationData[i];
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p[0], p[1]);
          bounds.extend(latlng);

          var icon = { url: '<?php echo base_url();?>assets/frontend/assets/images/location_pin1.png', // url     
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 70), // scaled size     
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin     
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor 
          };

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            draggable: true, // enables drag & drop
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            icon: icon
          });


          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            window.location.href = this.url;
          });

        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: what is var LocationData = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>; in your answer code??..im try to fetch different location latitude and longitude value from database and all place display on map.  ..but currently only one place marker diplay on map...,i try using loop for display all places on map